# String input using getchar()

Tags: c, getchar

The following code uses getchar() to accept a line of input.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
 char *rawString = (char *)malloc(200*sizeof(char));
 char *rawStringInitial = rawString;
 char c;
 c=getchar();
 while(c!='\n')
 {
  *rawString=c;
  rawString++;
  c=getchar();
 }
 *rawString='\0';
 printf("\n[%s]\n",rawStringInitial);
 return(0);
}
```

While typing, if I press backspace, shouldn't it also be received by getchar() & stored in the rawString-pointed location? However the output simply shows the final string without any special characters. Could someone explain why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Standard input is (usually) buffered; non-printing characters like backspace are handled by the terminal server, and library functions like `getchar()` will never see them.

If you need to read raw keystrokes, then you will need to use something outside of the C standard library.

Comment: I am facing the similar problem. Can you tell what function i can use ?

Comment: That depends on the platform you're on.  If you're on a *nix system, you could use ncurses.  I'm not sure what the equivalents would be in a modern Windows environment.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include<stdio.h>     
#include<conio.h>
#include<string.h>

void get_string(char *string);

void main(){
char *stringVar;
clrscr();
printf("Enter String : ");
get_string(stringVar);
printf("String Enter : %s",stringVar);
getch();
}

void get_string(char *string){
char press;int i=0;
do{
press=getch();
  if(press!=8){
  printf("%c",press);
  string[i]=press;
  i++;
  }
  else if(i>0){printf("\b%c\b",0);sting[i]=NULL;i--;}
}while(press!13);
}
```

This is Will Work.