# how to scan a string in C++

Tags: c++, string, loops

How do I scan a string character by character and print each character in a separate line, I'm thinking of storing the string in an array and use the for loop for printing, but I don't know how.... please help !!!

here is my code :

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
  string str;
  char option;

  cout << "Do you want to enter a string? \n";
  cout << " Enter 'y' to enter string or 'n' to exit \n\n";
  cin >> option ;

  while ( option != 'n' & option != 'y')
  {
    cout << "Invalid option chosen, please enter a valid y or n \n";
    cin >> option;
  }

  if (option == 'n')
    return 1;
  else if (option == 'y')
  {
    cout << "Enter a string \n";
    cin >> str;
    cout << "The string you entered is :" << str << endl;
  }

  system("pause");
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please properly format your question.

Comment: getchar() function from c defined in stdio.h works well in c++, reads input character by character.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3659109/string-input-using-getchar

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
for (int i=0; i<str.length(); i++)
    cout << str[i] << endl;
```

that's it :)

Answer (score 2):

You can simple do this to access string char by char

```
for(int i=0;i < str.length();i++)
   cout << str[i];
```

Answer (score 1):

There are at least three options to do it. Using ordinary *for* loop, and using `<algorithm>` library's functions *copy* or *for_each*:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

void f( char c) {
    c = c + 1; // do your processing
    std::cout << c << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    std::string str = "string";

    // 1st option
    for ( int i = 0; i < str.length(); ++i)
    std::cout << str[i] << std::endl;

    // 2nd option
    std::copy( str.begin(), str.end(), 
                       std::ostream_iterator<char>( std::cout, "\n"));

    // 3rd option
    std::for_each( str.begin(), str.end(), f); // to apply additional processing

    return 0;
}
```

http://ideone.com/HoErRl